QGIS / SCP plugin / Aster function / hdf file / Error 37 Unable to calculate. Metadata error
I have a blocking problem with the SCP plugin under QGIS when I try to load a .hdf file via the ASTER functionality.
When loading my hdf file (selecting the destination folder), I get the following error:

Error [37]: Unable to calculate. Metadata error

I know that the hdf file I'm trying to load is not corrupted, as this same file is being used by colleagues without any problems.
I don't know if this has anything to do with it, but I have retrieved my qgis error logs and I got these 3 default lines:
#SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin_v7-master.maininterface.settings-testSNAPSubprocess 470 ERROR exception: [WinError 87] Invalid parameter

#SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin_v7-master.maininterface.settings-testSNAPSubprocess 476 subprocess: 1

#SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin_v7-master.maininterface.settings-testSNAPSubprocess 484 test: Fail

Any ideas?
Versions of programs used :

SCP : 7.10.11
Python: 3.9.13
Matplotlib: 3.8.4
Scipy : 1.13.0
QGIS : 3.34.6


solved by granting administrator rights to the file and uploading it from local disk only
